# trying to load php only once with jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have Jquery set up so when I click on a button it loads in the PHP from another page. Currently it loads this every time I click the button. I would like to have it so it only loads the content once.

Here is my code:

```
//initially hides all containers
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.aboutcontainer,.contactcontainer,.homecontainer,.portfoliocontainer,.musiccontainer').hide();
});

//home page must show as first page on arrival
$( document ).ready(function () {
    $(".homecontainer").show();
});

//load about page
//button to start animation
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#about').click(function () {

        //fades unwanted pages
        $('.homecontainer,.musiccontainer, .portfoliocontainer, .contactcontainer').fadeOut({queue: false, duration: 700}); 

        //animates up unwanted pages
        $('.homecontainer, .musiccontainer, .portfoliocontainer, .contactcontainer').animate({
            'margin-Top' : "-1000px",  
        },400, 'easeInBack');

        //brings in selected page with a 0.7 second pause       
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.aboutcontainer ').fadeIn({
                queue: false,
                duration: 100
            });
            $(".aboutcontainer").animate({
                marginTop: "115px",
            },1200,'easeOutQuint');
        }, 700 );

        //loads in selected page content
        setTimeout(function() {
            $( ".aboutcontainer" ).load( "about.php" );
        }, 1200 );

    });
});
```

Also I am experiencing difficulty with the page not loading the change page functionality when I open it in incognito mode.

Here is a link to the site: http://benliger.webatu.com

Why would this be?

Comment: Have a variable set up which is empty to start with, on click check if the var is empty, if it is, get the page via AJAX and store it in the var, if the var isn't empty, return the var instead of running the AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow an event handler to run only once, use `.one()` rather than `.click()` (which is a shortcut to `.on("click"...`).

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/one

Comment: hmmm but its only the .load function that I want to run only once. Your suggestion would mean the .animate features would no longer run either correct?

Comment: @BenLiger Correct. Either split that portion into its own event handler using `.one()` for the binding or set a flag that saves state (used to determine if the `.load()` function has run or not and if so, don't run it again).

Comment: ok, both good suggestions. The second option sounds more practical for what im after. Could you recommend how to set a flag that saves the state?

Comment: ok so i tried adding this to the script:$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('#about').one(function () {
   setTimeout(function() {
$( ".aboutcontainer" ).load( "about.php" );
}, 1200 );
});
}); but now it doesnt load it?

Comment: woops was missing the "click" part. Works fine now. My second question still stands though, why are my functions not loading at all in incognito?

Comment: @BenLiger Is JS running when you load the page in an incognito tab? Other than that I suggest using `$(function () { ... })` rather than `$(document).ready(function () { ... })` as the former will fire even after the `document.ready` event has fired.

Comment: thanks Jasper and yes JS is running in incognito. Will make the suggested changes :)